# Jquery Flask capturing checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, flask

I am trying to capture the data from checkbox by assigning value in jquery and passing it to backend each time search is run by the user. It is not working for me, tried several ways.

Use case: As a user I would like to search and be able to check for various search options.

**template:**

```
$('a#process_input').bind('click', function () {
    $.getJSON('/background_process', {
    checkbox1: $('input[name="checkbox1"]').val(),
    input_search: $('input[name="input_search"]').val(),
    },

    function (data) {
        ul.empty();
        $.each(data.result, function (index, element) {

        ...
        ... <some irrelevant code...>

        <input type=text size=40 name=input_search>
        <a href=# id=process_input>
            <button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
        </a>
    </form>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <p>Please select allergy options below:</p>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox1"/>Allergy 1
```

**backend**

```
@app.route('/background_process', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def background_process():
    try:
        checkbox1 = request.args.get("something")

        search_word = request.args.get('input_search', 0, type=str)

        if search_word:

            return jsonify(result=yummly_search(search_word, checkbox1))
        else:
            return jsonify(result='Try again.')
except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not comfortable with getJSON function but the other way to do it is ajax. Here is a runnable code, I hope it helps:
html:

```
<input type=text size=40 name="input_search">
<a href=# id=process_input>
    <button class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
</a>

<p>Please select allergy options below:</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"/>Allergy 1

<div id="login_result"></div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#process_input").bind('click', function () {
            var login_result = $('#login_result');
            var input_search = $('[name="input_search"]').val();
            var checkbox1 = $('[name="checkbox1"]').is(":checked");
            console.log(input_search);
            console.log(checkbox1);
            var list = new FormData()
            list.append("input_search", input_search)
            list.append("checkbox1", checkbox1)
            var urlBackgroundProcess = "{{ url_for('background_process') }}";
            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlBackgroundProcess,
                data: list,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    login_result.html(msg.data);
                    console.log("AJAX ok 2!");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

and the flask back end:

```
@app.route('/background_process',methods=['GET','POST'])
def background_process():
    msg=''
    if request.form.get("input_search"):
        msg=('I got that search pattern at the back end: \'%s\' \n the checkbox value is set to: \'%s\' ') \
            % (request.form.get("input_search"),request.form.get("checkbox1"))
    else:
        msg='I got the Ajax call but cannot read the data, try again! :('
    return jsonify(data=msg)
```

Comment: what was the problem than? you were "trying to capture the data from checkbox by assigning value in jquery and passing it to backend each time search is run by the user. It is not working for me, tried several ways" and the my posting exactly solved that problem actually..